# Where can I read what ns3 module needs to be built?

Tags: ns-3

I work on Windows 7 & I must use the ns3 network simulator, so I install the Cygwin emulator. I successfully download the ns3 from the official cite and install it, but six modules wasn't been installed. I think it's because when I install Cygwin, I didn't install some packages, and these ns3 modules needs in this packages. So, there was the message:

```
Modules not built (see ns-3 tutorial for explanation):
brite                     click                     fd-net-device
openflow                  tap-bridge                visualizer
```

I found the ns3 tutorial (pdf file on the off. cite), but I can't find in these document what should I do to successfully built these modules! There is just an installation steps and some examples! I tried to run the test & I the test return me

```
0 of 0 tests passed (0 passed, 0 skipped, 0 failed, 0 crashed, 0 valgrind errors)
```

So, I think I will not be able to work with ns3 for now, because no one tests can be passed! **Where can I read about what I must to update/install in Cygwin** (maybe, install other version of gcc, or install java etc) **to build more modules successfully?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those modules require another additional software besides NS3 since these modules developed by integrating/using another projects.

You can find how to install and using it in their respected NS3 module documentation page or NS3 Wiki

- Brite : https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/brite.html
- OpenFlow : https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/openflow-switch.html
- Click : https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/click.html
- visualizer : https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/PyViz
- Tap-Bridge : required to build in linux based OS
- fd-net-device : required to build in linux based OS

TapBridge and emulation features aspects depend on Linux and those components are not enabled on the Windows via Cygwin. If you want to serious work on NS3 and still need Windows, consider virtualization of a popular Linux platform https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_use_VirtualBox_to_run_simulations_on_Windows_machines and https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_use_VMware_to_set_up_virtual_networks_%28Windows%29

Unless, you need these modules. You can skip it. It is not required to have it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I think I strongly need to use the NS3 $ I will try Oracle Virtual Box.